# How to handle security on website with users, asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, security

Im a rookie in asp.net and have managed to make a funktional webapp. I have a login page that also works correctly and checks username and Password from my mssql db.

My Problem is that i don't know how i can disable all my other sites if your not logged in? At the Moment i can access all my pages if i only now the URL.

So how can i track if im logged in and disable the sites and also i Need to know how to make a logout link that clears all Cookies or whatever it is that saves the Information.

I know this is probably a doublepost but i havent found anything that exactly explains my Problem until now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `authentication` modules, specifically `FormsAuthentication`.

Start here ... http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication